# Login problem in Ubuntu 14.04 as user

Tags: login

I am unable to login with my username and passwords. I can only login as guest.

My home partition is full. Only root (/) partition has about 24 GB space. It may either be caused by low disc space or many failure login attempts by my pc repairer.

Comment: You cannot login (ie. you don't have a  password), or are you immediately logged out when you login.

Comment: I HV password.when I try to login then only the blank wallpaper is seen.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to login on a console. For that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and at the `login:` prompt give your username, then on the `password:` prompt give your password.

Once you are login either clean up, or move things from `/home` to `/`.

Cleaning up can e.g. be done by removing the `.cache`. You can first try to see how much Mb that would bring you, then remove it and finally check the free space on the partition:

```
 du -sm ~/.cache
 rm -rf ~/.cache
 df -h /home
```

Assuming that you have used the system for browsing etc, the removing the `~/.cache` should free up enough space to login using the graphics screen once more (press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> (maybe F7) to switch back to the graphical login page). Make sure to free up enough space to not let this happen again.

Comment: Here I am able to login but unable to clean cache.terminal said -du: cannot access '~/.cache' no such file or directory.

Comment: @user1679555 It might be that you don't have a cache, although I find that strange. You will need to find other stuff you can remove, or move (using `mv src dst`). What is taking your discspace and how much do you have on /home anyway

Answer (score 0):

Switch on your computer.

Press and hold the `Shift key`, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with `recovery mode`

Your computer should display a menu with a number of options.

Select in this order, lines say, `fsck` `clean` and `network` `root` or `netroot`

In the terminal run:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
rm -rf /home/*/.local/share/Trash/*/** &> /dev/null
rm -rf home/*/.cache/*/** &> /dev/null
reboot
```